# Web app to easily create Cornell Notes

Tags: gratis, web-apps, note-taking

The [Cornell Notes system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornell_Notes) is a great way to summarise topics, but they are kinda tedious to make, and printing out templates isn't an option for me (I want them digital and preferably editable).

So, is there a web app that:

- is free
- lets me make Cornell Notes easily (i.e. provides a nice interface for me to add keywords and then the explanation)
- allows me to export the notes I make as a Word document (.doc(x)) or, at least PDF

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this template](https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=1iHNrwqjACiGMBaHm_axib5Cr2syhqZeX6NDhgK_py7A&mode=public&ddrp=1) for Google Documents to take your notes. It is free (provided you have a Google account) and editable directly from the web interface of Documents (and will be saved to Google Drive). From there you can save the document in a lot of formats, like .docx and .pdf, just click on file -> save as. Also there is [this](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s506/sh/1ed7c413-fd67-4938-90b9-504a573d312f/b6aba4c4c0bc2818) Evernote's template that you could edit from the web interface.

Comment: Hmmm Didn't think of using Google Drive! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Notzapp is a online web app that works good and very easy to use. Please try https://notzapp.online

Comment: Please improve your answer by describing its advantages